# Need help creating dictionary from csv excel file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have an assignment to create a function loadResults where the number, time, name and surnames of the runners are stored, and returns a list of dictionaries with this information.  The keys for the dictionary are: “number”, “name”,  “surname”, “time”. So far I have:

```
def loadResults():


    myFile = open("marathon.csv", "r")

    number = []

    for line in myFile:

       info = line.split(',')
       s = {}
       s['number'] = info[0]
       s['time'] = info[1]
       s['firstname'] = info[2]
       s['surname'] = info[3:]
       number.append(s)

    myFile.close

    return number
```

however I then also have to write a function displayTime that receives the list of runners and the number of a runner and displays the name and the time. For which I have:

```
def displayTime(time,number,firstname):

    for s in number:
      if s['number'] == time:
        print(s['name'])


    runners = loadResults()
    displayTime(number,'3070')
```

Unfortunately I am not getting anywhere with this any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please correct your code formatting.

Comment: Can you please display some sample data?

Comment: Can you post your entire code? Maybe there is a mistake with your file opening (have you tried using the "with" method?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csv.DictReader`:

```
import csv
with open('your_file') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
```

Then `reader` is the dictionary.

If the csv file don't have the keys on the first row you can use `fieldnames`:

```
import csv
with open('your_file') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=['number', 'name', 'surname', 'time'])
```